Player Sliding After Collision with Rigidbody2D Movement
I'm working on a 2D top-down game in Unity, and I’m using a Rigidbody2D to control the player’s movement. However, I’m encountering a problem where the player slides slowly after colliding with objects, even though I expect the player to stop moving once a collision occurs. The sliding happens despite setting the player’s velocity to zero in OnCollisionEnter2D.
Video of the issue:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OTRkKTOclwBj_V_ZSbWBRchUsQC79HWn/view
Here’s a snippet of my player movement code:
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {
[SerializeField] float speed = 10f;
private Vector2 movement;
private Rigidbody2D rb;

private void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

private void Update()
{
    Vector2 moveDirection = Vector2.zero;

    if (Keyboard.current.wKey.isPressed)
    {
        moveDirection.y = 1;
    }

    moveDirection.x += movement.x;
    moveDirection.y += movement.y;

    if (moveDirection.magnitude > 1)
    {
        moveDirection.Normalize();
    }

    if (moveDirection.magnitude > 0)
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveDirection * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
}

private void OnMovement(InputValue value)
{
    movement = value.Get<Vector2>(); 
}

}
Steps I’ve taken to resolve the issue:

I’ve added rb.velocity = Vector3.zero inside OnCollisionEnter2D().
I’ve ensured that I’m using Rigidbody2D for movement, not directly modifying the player’s transform position.
I’m using MovePosition() in FixedUpdate() to ensure smooth physics-based movement.

What I’ve tried:

Moving player logic to FixedUpdate().
Setting friction on the player's collider by adding a Physics Material 2D with friction set to 0.

The problem persists:
Despite these attempts, the player continues to slide after a collision. How can I prevent this sliding behavior and ensure the player comes to a complete stop when colliding with other objects?
Additional info:
The player object has a Rigidbody2D with default settings.
The game uses Unity’s new input system.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Well i think that means the player object receives force after onCollisionEnter fired. Changing the trigger to OnCollisionExit may mitigate the issue, but tbh i'm struggling to see what you're trying to achieve here. why do you wanna set player movement to zero after collision?
If your issue is player endlessly sliding, you can use built-in friction mechanism that will result in more realistic collisions than hard setting player velocity to zero, which will result in a very rigid "hard stop".

I see a problem,
    if (moveDirection.magnitude > 0)
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveDirection * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

here you should use rb.velocity = moveDirection * speed instead, to update the velocity, not the position. Now that we made this change we can remove the Vector2 movement variable and all of the instances where you add it to the MoveDirection. Not needing the 'Vector2 movement' means you can delete the OnMovement() function.
Then there is actual post directly on the Unity manual: It is important to understand that the actual position change will only occur during the next physics update therefore calling this method repeatedly without waiting for the next physics update will result in the last call being used. For this reason, it is recommended that it is called during the FixedUpdate callback.
That could be the reason, your character slides currently. If you want to keep the MovePosition(). You can try putting it in the FixedUpdate(). But I would forget that, MovePosition is meant for kinematic rigidbodies, which means you're basically telling the physics engine to treat your player like a brick with wheels and no real physics interaction.

Hey, when i replace
rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveDirection * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
with rb.velocity = moveDirection * speed
It solves the collision problem but it behaves in a way that I need to only click once on a direction (AWSD) and it goes straight to that direction without stopping even though im not holding the key down

Unfortunately it does not solve the sliding issue :/
thought it did but it did not

Ok, I made a quick Unity project and aplied some changes. I removed the Vector2 movement variable and the instance where you add it to the MoveDirection. I changed the OnCollisionEnter2D() to OnCollisionStay2D(), just so it checks for the whole duration of the contact. I think the Vector2 movement variable was the problem. In this code, where you use rb.velocity = moveDirection * speed you don't need the Vector2 movement, you can even delete the OnMovement() function.

These changes will fix the no stopping movement too
